# Tic-Tac_Toe computer algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have been working on a simple **Tic-Tac-Toe** game and have run into a brick wall.

While most of the games functionality is in place, I am lacking the crucial algorithm needed to place the computer tile appropriately.

I am in need of an algorithm that can **search a 3x3 grid of tiles** and **search for where to best positon the computer tile** in the grid.

I'd be grateful for any direction or insight as to how I can design this algorithm.

Incomplete Tic Tac Toe Algorithm:

```
function placeComputerTile(el){
  if(computerTurn === true && userTurn === false){
    var tileIsEmpty = true;
    // If the selected tile has at least one child,
    // do not allow placement of another tile.
    if (el.firstChild) {
        tileIsEmpty = false;
      }
    if(tileIsEmpty === true){
      cloneComputerIcon();
    }
    el.appendChild(newComputerIcon);
    addClass(el, "x");
    newComputerIcon.style.display = null;
  }
}
```

Full Javascript:

```
var gameIcons    = document.getElementsByClassName('gameIcon');
var turnDisplays = document.getElementsByClassName('turnDisplay');

for (var i = 0; i < gameIcons.length; i++) {
  gameIcons[i].style.display = 'none';
}

for (var i = 0; i < turnDisplays.length; i++) {
  turnDisplays[i].style.display = 'none';
}

var userTurn     = true;
var computerTurn = false;
var currentTurn  = 1;
var maxTurn      = 10;

var userTurnDisplay     = document.getElementById("userTurnDisplay");
var computerTurnDisplay = document.getElementById("computerTurnDisplay");

function evaluateTurn(){
  currentTurn += 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < maxTurn; i++) {
    if(currentTurn % 2 === 0){
      userTurn     = true;
      computerTurn = false;
    }else if(currentTurn % 2 !== 0){
      userTurn     = false;
      computerTurn = true;
    }
  }
  if(currentTurn === maxTurn){
    alert("Draw!");
    userTurnDisplay.style.display = "none";
    computerTurnDisplay.style.display = "none";
  }
  //Change display depending on players turn.
  if(userTurn === true && currentTurn !== maxTurn) {
    computerTurnDisplay.style.display = null;
    userTurnDisplay.style.display = "none";
  }else if(computerTurn === true && currentTurn !== maxTurn){
    userTurnDisplay.style.display = null;
    computerTurnDisplay.style.display = "none";
  }
}

var cloneUserIcon = function(){
  var userIcon = document.getElementById("userIcon");
  newUserIcon = userIcon.cloneNode(true);
}

var cloneComputerIcon = function(){
  var computerIcon = document.getElementById("computerIcon");
  newComputerIcon = computerIcon.cloneNode(true);
}

function addClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.add(className)
  else if (!hasClass(el, className)) el.className += " " + className
}

function placeUserTile(el){
  if(userTurn === true && computerTurn === false){
    var tileIsEmpty  = true;
    // If the selected tile has at least one child,
    // do not allow placement of another tile.
    if (el.firstChild) {
      tileIsEmpty = false;
    }
    if(tileIsEmpty === true){
      cloneUserIcon();
    }
    el.appendChild(newUserIcon);
    addClass(el, "o");
    newUserIcon.style.display = null;
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                        computer move logic                                //
//                                                                           //

function placeComputerTile(el){
  if(computerTurn === true && userTurn === false){
    var tileIsEmpty = true;
    // If the selected tile has at least one child,
    // do not allow placement of another tile.
    if (el.firstChild) {
        tileIsEmpty = false;
      }
    if(tileIsEmpty === true){
      cloneComputerIcon();
    }
    el.appendChild(newComputerIcon);
    addClass(el, "x");
    newComputerIcon.style.display = null;
  }
}

//                                                                           //
//                                                                           //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Search an array of tiles.
function hasTile(tilesArray){

   var allHaveChild = tilesArray.length > 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < tilesArray.length; i++){
     if(!tilesArray[i].firstChild){
       allHaveChild = false;
     }
   }
   if(allHaveChild)
    return true;
   else
    return false;
}

function hasClass(element, className) {
  return element.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(element.className);
}

// Row 1 Tiles
const R1C1             = document.getElementById('r1c1');
const R1C2             = document.getElementById('r1c2');
const R1C3             = document.getElementById('r1c3');
//
// // Row 2 Tiles
const R2C1             = document.getElementById('r2c1');
const R2C2             = document.getElementById('r2c2');
const R2C3             = document.getElementById('r2c3');
//
// // Row 3 Tiles
const R3C1             = document.getElementById('r3c1');
const R3C2             = document.getElementById('r3c2');
const R3C3             = document.getElementById('r3c3');

//Set of all row tiles
var rowOneTiles        = [R1C1,R1C2,R1C3];
var rowTwoTiles        = [R2C1,R2C2,R2C3];
var rowThreeTiles      = [R3C1,R3C2,R3C3];

// Set of all column tiles
var columnOneTiles     = [R1C1,R2C1,R3C1];
var columnTwoTiles     = [R1C2,R2C2,R3C2];
var columnThreeTiles   = [R1C3,R2C3,R3C3];

//Set of left-diagonal & right-diagonal tiles
var leftDiagonalTiles  = [R1C1,R2C2,R3C3];
var rightDiagonalTiles = [R1C3,R2C2,R3C1];

function checkRow1(){
  // If the entire row is filled:
  if(hasTile(rowOneTiles)){
    var el_1 = rowOneTiles[0];
    var el_2 = rowOneTiles[1];
    var el_3 = rowOneTiles[2];
    if(hasClass(el_1,"x") && hasClass(el_2,"x") && hasClass(el_3,"x")){
      alert("Sorry, you've lost.");
    }else if(hasClass(el_1,"o") && hasClass(el_2,"o") && hasClass(el_3,"o")){
      alert("Congratulations, you've won!");
    }
  }
}

function checkRow2(){
  // If the entire row is filled:
  if(hasTile(rowTwoTiles)){
    var el_1 = rowTwoTiles[0];
    var el_2 = rowTwoTiles[1];
    var el_3 = rowTwoTiles[2];
    if(hasClass(el_1,"x") && hasClass(el_2,"x") && hasClass(el_3,"x")){
      alert("Sorry, you've lost.");
    }else if(hasClass(el_1,"o") && hasClass(el_2,"o") && hasClass(el_3,"o")){
      alert("Congratulations, you've won!");
    }
  }
}

function checkRow3(){
  // If the entire row is filled:
  if(hasTile(rowThreeTiles)){
    var el_1 = rowThreeTiles[0];
    var el_2 = rowThreeTiles[1];
    var el_3 = rowThreeTiles[2];
    if(hasClass(el_1,"x") && hasClass(el_2,"x") && hasClass(el_3,"x")){
      alert("Sorry, you've lost.");
    }else if(hasClass(el_1,"o") && hasClass(el_2,"o") && hasClass(el_3,"o")){
      alert("Congratulations, you've won!");
    }
  }
}

function checkColumn1(){
  // If the entire row is filled:
  if(hasTile(columnOneTiles)){
    var el_1 = columnOneTiles[0];
    var el_2 = columnOneTiles[1];
    var el_3 = columnOneTiles[2];
    if(hasClass(el_1,"x") && hasClass(el_2,"x") && hasClass(el_3,"x")){
      alert("Sorry, you've lost.");
    }else if(hasClass(el_1,"o") && hasClass(el_2,"o") && hasClass(el_3,"o")){
      alert("Congratulations, you've won!");
    }
  }
}

function checkColumn2(){
  // If the entire row is filled:
  if(hasTile(columnTwoTiles)){
    var el_1 = columnTwoTiles[0];
    var el_2 = columnTwoTiles[1];
    var el_3 = columnTwoTiles[2];
    if(hasClass(el_1,"x") && hasClass(el_2,"x") && hasClass(el_3,"x")){
      alert("Sorry, you've lost.");
    }else if(hasClass(el_1,"o") && hasClass(el_2,"o") && hasClass(el_3,"o")){
      alert("Congratulations, you've won!");
    }
  }
}

function checkColumn3(){
  // If the entire row is filled:
  if(hasTile(columnThreeTiles)){
    var el_1 = columnThreeTiles[0];
    var el_2 = columnThreeTiles[1];
    var el_3 = columnThreeTiles[2];
    if(hasClass(el_1,"x") && hasClass(el_2,"x") && hasClass(el_3,"x")){
      alert("Sorry, you've lost.");
    }else if(hasClass(el_1,"o") && hasClass(el_2,"o") && hasClass(el_3,"o")){
      alert("Congratulations, you've won!");
    }
  }
}

function checkLeftDiagonal(){
  // If the entire row is filled:
  if(hasTile(leftDiagonalTiles)){
    var el_1 = leftDiagonalTiles[0];
    var el_2 = leftDiagonalTiles[1];
    var el_3 = leftDiagonalTiles[2];
    if(hasClass(el_1,"x") && hasClass(el_2,"x") && hasClass(el_3,"x")){
      alert("Sorry, you've lost.");
    }else if(hasClass(el_1,"o") && hasClass(el_2,"o") && hasClass(el_3,"o")){
      alert("Congratulations, you've won!");
    }
  }
}

function checkRightDiagonal(){
  // If the entire row is filled:
  if(hasTile(rightDiagonalTiles)){
    var el_1 = rightDiagonalTiles[0];
    var el_2 = rightDiagonalTiles[1];
    var el_3 = rightDiagonalTiles[2];
    if(hasClass(el_1,"x") && hasClass(el_2,"x") && hasClass(el_3,"x")){
      alert("Sorry, you've lost.");
    }else if(hasClass(el_1,"o") && hasClass(el_2,"o") && hasClass(el_3,"o")){
      alert("Congratulations, you've won!");
    }
  }
}

function checkForWin(){
  checkRow1();
  checkRow2();
  checkRow3();
  checkColumn1();
  checkColumn2();
  checkColumn3();
  checkLeftDiagonal();
  checkRightDiagonal();
}

function main(el){
  evaluateTurn();
  if(userTurn === true){
    placeUserTile(el);
  }
  if(computerTurn === true){
    placeComputerTile(el);
  }
  checkForWin();
}
```

Full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/game.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="tileContainer">
      <!-- id listed by row-column notation. -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile rowOne columnOne"   id="r1c1" onclick="main(this)"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile rowOne columnTwo"   id="r1c2" onclick="main(this)"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile rowOne columnThree" id="r1c3" onclick="main(this)"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile rowTwo columnOne"   id="r2c1" onclick="main(this)"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile rowTwo columnTwo"   id="r2c2" onclick="main(this)"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile rowTwo columnThree" id="r2c3" onclick="main(this)"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile rowThree columnOne"   id="r3c1" onclick="main(this)"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile rowThree columnTwo"   id="r3c2" onclick="main(this)"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile rowThree columnThree" id="r3c3" onclick="main(this)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of tile container -->

    <div class="container" id="turnDisplayContainer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-6 turnDisplay" id="userTurnDisplay">
          <h4>Your Turn</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-6 turnDisplay" id="computerTurnDisplay">
          <h4>Computer's Turn</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <img class="img img-responsive gameIcon" src="assets/img/green-ring.png" alt="Green Ring Icon" id="userIcon" />
    <img class="img img-responsive gameIcon" src="assets/img/red-x.png"      alt="Red X Icon"      id="computerIcon" />

    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/game.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Full CSS:

```
h1{
  text-align: center;
}

h4{
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: auto;
}

.row{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.tile{
  width:             100px;
  height:            100px;
  border:   1px solid blue;
  background-color:  white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link:
http://userpages.umbc.edu/~hoban/FLEX/CourseDocs/TicTacToe.pdf

Think about how **you** play tic-tac-toe as a series of if-then statements:
"IF I go first, THEN put an X in the middle".
"IF my opponent has two O's in a row (sum of the count of O's in the row, column or diagonal = 2) THEN put an X in that row"
etc. etc.

Articulate the rules that you use yourself when playing.

Answer (score 1):

*scroll down to bottom if you don't want to be bored to death and want to see actual code*

The typical algorithms used for this are [minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) or [alpha beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning), alpha beta being an optimized version of minimax (probably a little overkill for tac tic toe). Both are basically a depth first search of the possible positions you can get, where you're searching for the best possible position. Here's a basic example of what procedure looks like (an attempted explanation bellow):

```
     max(8,2)  8
             /   \
  min(9,8)  8    2  min(7,2)
           / \  / \
          9  8 7  2
```

Here's my implementation of minimax:

```java
/**
 * initialize MiniMax(0, player1) where player1 is computer
 * @param depth current depth or degree
 * @param player either MAX or MIN
 * @return int[] {score,bestRow,bestCol}
 */
int[] miniMax(int depth, int player) {

    // list of possible columns to place a checker
    List<int[]> moves = nextMoves();

    int bestRow = -1;
    int bestCol = -1;
    int previousPlayer = (player+1) & 1;

    // if you reached maximum depth or node is a terminal node (game ending position)
    // i.e. if (current position has a 3 in row || you reached maximum depth || the board is full (draw))
    if (isWin(previousPlayer) || (depth == this.depth) || moves.isEmpty()) {
        return new int[]{eval(), bestRow, bestCol};
    }
    // best current value
    int v;  

    // if its MAX's turn (computer)
    if (player==0) {
        // assume worst case, MAX value is -infinity, 
        // and if better value appears replace v with it
        v = -inf;
        // for each available move
        for (int[] move : moves) {  // move = {row,column}
            makeMove(move[0],move[1],0);
            int score = miniMax(depth+1,1)[0];
            undoMove(move[0],move[1],0);

            // if score is better then update v 
            if (score > v) {
                v = score;
                bestRow = move[0];
                bestCol = move[1];
            }
        }
        return new int[] {v,bestRow,bestCol};
    }

    // if its MIN's turn (opponent)
    else {
        // assume worst case, MIN value is infinity, 
        // and if better value appears replace v with it
        v = inf;
        // for each available move
        for (int[] move : moves) {  // move = {row,column}
            makeMove(move[0],move[1],1); // make move
            int score = miniMax(depth+1,0)[0];
            undoMove(move[0],move[1],1); // undo move

            // if score is better then update v 
            if (v > score) {
                v = score;
                bestRow = move[0];
                bestCol = move[1];
            }
        }
        return new int[] {v,bestRow,bestCol};
    }
}
```

For the 2 players you assign each a roll:

```
1. maximizing player (the computer) 
2. minimizing player (the computer's opponent)
```

The `maximizing player` takes the `max` of the possible moves that are available, similarly the `minimizing player` takes the `min` of the possible moves that are available.

To clarify this operation, given a position you're looking at (or the position resulting from 1 of your possible moves) you assign it a value through some evaluation function or [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science)). For example if I was playing `X` and had the position:

```
=======
|O|X| |
=======
| |X|O|
=======
| |X| |
=======
```

the value given would  be `∞` (or some large number) since I have already won. But if I had the position:

```
=======
|O| | |
=======
|O|X| |
=======
|X| |X|
=======
```

while `X` hasn't won yet (no 3 in row on board) there is a guaranteed win for `X`. But if we wanted to give a value to the ***current*** state of the board, assuming we let positive value mean the position is good for `X`, we would make it positive. To satisfy that, you could, for example, assuming there are no 3 in rows, count all open 2 in rows  and return that as the value of the position:

```
value (position){
    if position has a 3 in row return infinity 
    result = 0
    add 1 to result for each 2 in row with an empty space in between
    return result
}
```

So for the above example you would give it a value of `2` (the bottom horizontal plus the diagonal going up towards the right). There are other more efficient ways of doing an evaluation function but the above is sufficient. *You could also just `return infinity` if there is a win on the board but your search depth could be large, not that that's an issue in tic tac toe*.

Here's the java class with main method (and example) at the bottom if you want to try it out:

```java
import java.util.*;
public class f {

    int inf = 1000000000; // infinity
    int depth;

    char computer = 'O';
    char opponent = 'X';


    /*
    [0] = computer
    [1] = opponent
    the computer and opponent's moves are stored in binary numbers
    where 1 represents that a checker is there and 0 represents an
    empty space

    =======
    |O|O| |
    =======
    | |X| |
    =======
    | |X| |
    =======

    the above board would be represented by:
        computer = 110000000   (computer is 'O')
        opponent = 000010010   (opponent is 'X')

    */
    int[] playerBoards = {0b100010000,0b000000000};


    // count number of bits in i
    int count(int i){
        int n = 0;
        while(i!=0){
            i = i & (i-1);
            n++;
        }
        return n;
    }


    void printBoard(){
        int p1 = playerBoards[0];
        int p2 = playerBoards[1];
        int count = 1 << 8;
        String line = "";
        String border = "=======";

        System.out.println(border);
        for(int i=0; i < 12; i++){
            if ((i+1)%4 == 0) {
                line = "|" + line;
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.println(border);
                line = "";
                continue;
            }
            if ((p1 & count) > 0) {
                line += computer +"|";
            }
            else if ((p2 & count) > 0){
                line += opponent +"|";
            }
            else line += " |";

            count = count >> 1;
        }
    }

    // turn on the nth bit
    void makeMove(int row,int col,int player){
        playerBoards[player] |= 1 << 8 - row*3 - col;
    }

    // turn off the nth bit
    void undoMove(int row,int col,int player){
        playerBoards[player] ^= 1 << 8 - row*3 - col;
    }

    List<int[]> nextMoves(){
        int p = playerBoards[0]^playerBoards[1];
        List<int[]> moves = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 8; i >= 0; i--){
            if((p & 1) == 0) moves.add(new int[]{i/3,i%3});
            p = p >> 1;
        }
        return moves;
    }

    // check if current position has a win (3 in row)
    boolean isWin(int player) {
        int board = playerBoards[player];

        // vertical
        if ((board & board>>3 & board>>6) != 0) return true;
        // horizontal
        if ((board & board>>1 & board>>2) != 0) return true;
        // left diagonal
        if ((board & board>>4 & board>>8) != 0) return true;
        // right diagonal
        if ((board & board>>2 & board>>4) != 0) return true;
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Static evaluation (heuristic): if there is an open 2 i.e. there is a 2 in row with an
     * empty space in between then add 1 to result
     *
     * @param player is either 0 or 1 for the computer and opponent respectively
     * @return the value of the current position
     */
    int evaluation(int player){
        int board = playerBoards[player];

        if (isWin(player)) return inf;
        int opponent = playerBoards[(player+1) & 1];
        int result = 0;


        // open vertical
        int a = board & (board<<3);
        int b = board & (board<<6);
        int c = (board << 3) & (board << 6);

        if (a!=0 && (a&(opponent<<6))==0)
            result += count(a);
        if (b!=0 && (b&(opponent<<3))==0)
            result += count(b);
        if (c!=0 && (c&opponent)==0)
            result += count(c);


        // open horizontal
        a = board & (board<<1);
        b = board & (board<<2);
        c = (board << 1) & (board << 2);

        if (a!=0 && (a&(opponent<<2))==0)
            result += count(a);
        if (b!=0 && (b&(opponent<<1))==0)
            result += count(b);
        if (c!=0 && (c&opponent)==0)
            result += count(c);


        // open left diagonal
        a = board & (board<<4);
        b = board & (board<<8);
        c = (board << 4) & (board << 8);

        if (a!=0 && (a&(opponent<<8))==0)
            result += count(a);
        if (b!=0 && (b&(opponent<<4))==0)
            result += count(b);
        if (c!=0 && (c&opponent)==0)
            result += count(c);


        // open rght diagonal
        a = board & (board<<2);
        b = board & (board<<4);
        c = (board << 2) & (board << 4);

        if (a!=0 && (a&(opponent<<4))==0)
            result += count(a);
        if (b!=0 && (b&(opponent<<2))==0)
            result += count(b);
        if (c!=0 && (c&opponent)==0)
            result += count(c);

        return result;
    }

    // player1's score - player2's score
    int eval() {return evaluation(0) - evaluation(1);}


    /**
     * initialize MiniMax(0, player1) where player1 is computer
     * @param depth current depth or degree
     * @param player either MAX or MIN
     * @return int[] {score,bestRow,bestCol}
     */
    int[] miniMax(int depth, int player) {


        // list of possible coordinates to place a checker
        List<int[]> moves = nextMoves();

        int bestRow = -1;
        int bestCol = -1;
        int previousPlayer = (player+1) & 1;



        // if you reached maximum depth or node is a terminal node (game ending position)
        // i.e. if (current position has a 3 in row || you reached maximum depth || the board is full (draw))
        if (isWin(previousPlayer) || (depth == this.depth) || moves.isEmpty()) {
            return new int[]{eval(), bestRow, bestCol};
        }

        int v;

        // if its MAX's turn (computer)
        if (player==0) {
            // assume worst case, MAX value is -infinity,
            // and if better value appears replace v with it
            v = -inf;
            // for each available move
            for (int[] move : moves) {  // move = {row,column}
                makeMove(move[0],move[1],0);
                int score = miniMax(depth+1,1)[0];
                undoMove(move[0],move[1],0);

                if (score > v) {
                    v = score;
                    bestRow = move[0];
                    bestCol = move[1];
                }
            }
            return new int[] {v,bestRow,bestCol};
        }

        // if its MIN's turn (opponent)
        else {
            // assume worst case, MIN value is infinity,
            // and if better value appears replace v with it
            v = inf;
            // for each available move
            for (int[] move : moves) {  // move = {row,column}
                makeMove(move[0],move[1],1); // make move
                int score = miniMax(depth+1,0)[0];
                undoMove(move[0],move[1],1); // undo move

                if (v > score) {
                    v = score;
                    bestRow = move[0];
                    bestCol = move[1];
                }
            }
            return new int[] {v,bestRow,bestCol};
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the best move: int[] {row, column}
     */
    int[] minMax(){
        int[] m = miniMax(0,0);
        return new int[] {m[1],m[2]};
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f o = new f();

        // the max depth (4 moves ahead)
        o.depth = 4;



        System.out.println("initial board:");
        o.printBoard();
        System.out.println();


        // get best move using miniMax {row, column}
        int[] bestMove = o.minMax();
        o.makeMove(bestMove[0],bestMove[1],0);

        System.out.println("board after computer move:");
        o.printBoard();


    }

}
```

output:

```
initial board:
=======
|O| | |
=======
| |O| |
=======
| | | |
=======

board after computer move:
=======
|O| | |
=======
| |O| |
=======
| | |O|
=======
```